# Processing lambda query result in C# after performing table join

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, datatable

So I have a query that joins two data tables together:

```
var results = (
   from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
   join t2 in table2.AsEnumerable() on
        new { a = t1["col1"], b= t1["col2"], c = t1["col3"] } equals
        new { a= t2["col1"], b= t2["col2"], c= t2["col3"] }
   into joinedComboTable
   select joinedComboTable);
```

and it produces a result whose type is `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<datarow>>"`

How am I to convert that to a `DataTable`? Tables 1 and Tables 2 are C# `DataTable`s. I do see 304 results which I can see through the debugger and the results.inner (Non-Public) parameter that I have `DataColumn`s and I can see 304 rows. But am unable to figure out how to get to actual result and have it saved into a `DataTable`.

UPDATE: 2020.01.23 @ 9:04pm

So, I checked out a couple options below and when I perform a results.ToList(), I get basically a list of 304 entries, but each row value is System.Data.DataRow[0]. I must be missing something....

[image: Visual Studio QuickWatch of data]

Iterating over this doesn't produce the desired results.

Comment: Read about Deferred Execution in LINQ. That is what you are seeing. To get the results call joinedComboTable.ToList().

Comment: IEnumerable of IEnumerable is like an array of arrays which does not resemble the structure of a table. could you provide an example with results populated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var table1 = new DataTable();
        table1.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
        table1.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));
        table1.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(string));
        table1.Columns.Add("col4", typeof(string));

        var row = table1.NewRow();
        row["col1"] = "1";
        row["col2"] = "1";
        row["col3"] = "1";
        row["col4"] = "something different";
        table1.Rows.Add(row);

        row = table1.NewRow();
        row["col1"] = "2";
        row["col2"] = "2";
        row["col3"] = "2";
        row["col4"] = "something different";
        table1.Rows.Add(row);

        var table2 = new DataTable();
        table2.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
        table2.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));
        table2.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(string));
        table2.Columns.Add("col4", typeof(string));

        row = table2.NewRow();
        row["col1"] = "1";
        row["col2"] = "1";
        row["col3"] = "1";
        row["col4"] = "Another different thing";
        table2.Rows.Add(row);

        var results = (
            from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
            join t2 in table2.AsEnumerable() on
                new { a = t1["col1"], b = t1["col2"], c = t1["col3"] } equals
                new { a = t2["col1"], b = t2["col2"], c = t2["col3"] }
                into joinedComboTable
            select joinedComboTable).ToList();

        //Result
        var newTable = results.FirstOrDefault()?.CopyToDataTable();

        //However to get col4 form table 2 you need to do this
        var result2 = (
            from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
            join t2 in table2.AsEnumerable() on
                new { a = t1["col1"], b = t1["col2"], c = t1["col3"] } equals
                new { a = t2["col1"], b = t2["col2"], c = t2["col3"] }
            select new { a = t1["col1"], b = t1["col2"], c = t1["col3"], d = t1["col4"], e = t2["col4"] });

        //Result
        var newTable2 = table1.Clone();
        newTable2.Columns.Add("col4FromTable2", typeof(string));

        foreach (var x1 in result2)
        {
            var r = newTable2.NewRow();
            r["col1"] = x1.a;
            r["col2"] = x1.b;
            r["col3"] = x1.c;
            r["col4"] = x1.d;
            r["col4FromTable2"] = x1.e;
            newTable2.Rows.Add(r);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The resulting table is to be 45 columns, so idea of having to define the outgoing columns is not something I want to explore. But I have two possible/viable solutions. Yours and the first response, so will look into both at the earliest opportunity and determine what will work.

Comment: @PavelBrun I am creating these columns for demonstration only, based on your given you can clone one of your Data Tables to get its structure. If you explain the end result you are willing to get maybe we could give a better solution.

Comment: I've updated your code to model a smaller version of my use-case. In my case, I have about 30 columns in table1 and 30 and 43 columns in table2 which will result in a 73 column table and 304 rows. Table1 has been dynamically built up in prior stages with other data points and one of the stages includes a pivot. The end result is a report of the days activity which goes into a database. As a side-bar, the above code does work to produce the desired result. I am trying to hopefully minimize having to have huge select statements, but this is a start for sure.

Comment: @PavelBrun the best way to minimize select statements and reduce round trips to the database is to perform your join inside the database. Also it is not a good practice performing these loops especially on large data sets.

Comment: I have a solution to my problem above. I will post it when I have some more time, but it involves moving to DataSets and using DataRelations instead of the above Lambda queries. Parse of my problem also was that I wasn't casting my row objects, so a true comparison was not being done.

Comment: @PavelBrun Yes as I remember you can create relationships between data tables within a data set.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first level by calling `var rows = result.FirstOrDefault()` to return an IEnumerable of rows. Create a new instance of the data table `var newtable = new DataTable();` then loop through to add the rows to the rows collection property of the new data table like so...

```
for(var i=0; i <= rows.Count(); i++)
     newtable.Rows.Add(rows[i]);
```

something like this should work for you.
Sorry for the typo.. I'm using my mobile phone